Who wins in this knight-placement game?
Two players take turns placing knights on the squares of a standard 8x8 chessboard, so that no knight can take another. The player who is unable to do this loses.  Which player has a winning strategy and how do they force a win?
Clarifications:
The players can only place knights on an empty square.
The color of the knights is not important.
Attribution:  Mathematical Circles (Russian Experience)


 The second player can always win


 By copying the first player's move with 180° rotational symmetry.
 The two pieces played each round will be on the same coloured squares, so cannot attack each other; and by symmetry if the first player's move is legal with respect to previously played pieces, then the second player's will be too.


This works (and +1) but I wonder whether there's a simpler strategy of rot13(nyjnlf cynpvat ba gur fnzr pbybe nf gur svefg cynlre). It seems that that would work too. Of course, the simpler strategy comes with a more difficult proof that it works.

note that this does not work if the square side is an odd number, because first player can then take the center

@msh210 Your suggestion doesn't work I think. Following it, you might end up with knights on every light coloured square except b3 and c2 after the second player's turn. This covers every dark square except a1, so the first player will then win on the next turn by playing there.

@sayanel - In the case of odd-sized boards, first player has a winning strategy. Their first move plays in the center, subsequent moves answer second player's previous move using the same strategy as this answer.

Mirroring (horizontal or vertical or both - which is the 180deg rotation) works too. You are placing knight on different coloured squares, but it can't be attacked by the previously placed knight as it is in a line, so by symmetry either both could be placed or neither could.
